# How do you configure Google Cloud load balancer back end to load a website hosted on a Windows Server VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do you configure Google Cloud load balancer back end to load a website hosted on a Windows Server VM?

Can the startup script from the Setting up a simple external HTTPS load balancer (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-https-lb-simple) example be changed to open a web application hosted on a Google Cloud VM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the Load balancer on a Windows Guest Environment as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/setting-up-network#configure_vms).

But the script on the guide you are referring to will not work for Windows as it is only for Debian OS. It is just a script for setting up the Apache service on the machine. As an alternative, you can check this [link](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-apache-on-a-windows-server/) on how to configure Apache on windows.

Comment: Alex,  thank you for the reply.  I am still struggling with this even after following the link you have provided.  I setup al load balancer with a target pool and I am still not getting the desired results.  Do you know of any examples that show how to configure a load balancer to work with a windows-server-2016 instance?  I am brand new working with Google Cloud.  Thank you.

Comment: This [Solution Article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-load-balanced-iis-web-servers) from the Google Cloud website may help you with easy to follow steps. I would also recommend for you to check the [How to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) article for a better composition of your questions.